# How to specify "any name" field for Yaml.Net

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, yamldotnet

I am trying to deserialize the specified piece of `YAML`, using `Yaml.Net` library:

```
version: '5'
infoFiles:
   <relative path to file 1>: <int number>
   <relative path to file 2>: <int number>
   ...
   <relative path to file N>: <int number>
```

E.g.:

```
dir1/file1 : '1'
dir2/dir3/file2 : '5"
```

To deserialize any YAML file we need to describe it using `C#` classes:

```
var deserializer = new Deserializer( null, new CamelCaseNamingConvention() );
var myYamlData = ( Yaml )deserializer.Deserialize( textReader, typeof( MyYamlDataClass ) );

...
class MyYamlDataClass
{
    public int Version;
    public **what type to use here?**[] InfoFiles;
}
```

So, how to describe the `InfoFiles` field in Yaml.Net terms?
The problem is what i **don't know** the field names on compile time.
So, `YamlAlias` probably will not help.

P.S. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/HD2JXM to see example of structure description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<string,int>`, also the fields should be properties. So the final class should look like:

```
public class MyYamlDataClass
{
  public int Version { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, int> InfoFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Also note you don't have to specify deserialization type at all. In this case deserializer reverts to `Dictionary<object,object>`.

```
var foo = @"version: '5'
infoFiles:
  patha: 1
  pathb: 2
  pathc: 3";

var deserializer = new Deserializer(null, new CamelCaseNamingConvention());
var bar = (Dictionary<object,object>)deserializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(foo));
```

Comment: Heh, i'm already find this solution myself :) However, thank you for your time. I'll mark your answer

Comment: Also, serialize this back is less trivial: `YamlDescriber describer = new YamlDescriber( _path ); describer.Append( "infoFiles: " )
      .NewLine()
      .Join( myYamlData.InfoFiles, ( i, d ) => d.Append( "  " ).Append( i.Key ).Append( ": '" ).Append( i.Value ).Append( "'" ), d => d.NewLine() )`